# How to disable the user from entering wrong passwords

Tags: php

I'm making login and registration system

For my website

But How to disable the user from entering wrong passwords

(after trying 5 times I want to disable him for 1 hour)

Comment: There are libraries which accomplish this already. I would recommend you search the web for it and use that, rather than trying to create your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives:

1. Start a session, set login_retry and a timestamp in a cookie.

session_start();

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['retry'] ) && $_COOKIE['retry'] > 4 ) {
    if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['timestamp'] ) {          // First failed attempt
        setcookie('timestamp', time() + 3600 );     // 3600 Seconds = 1 hour
    } else if ( $_COOKIE['timestamp'] > time() ) {  // Wait an hour
        echo 'The number of login attempts are exhausted. Pleas wait an hour for next retry!';
    } else {                                        // Timeout has passed
        setcookie('retry', 0 );
        unset( $_COOKIE['timestamp'] );
    }
} else {
    setcookie('retry', 0);
}            

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['username'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['password'] ) {
    if ( $_REQUEST['username'] == 'user' && $_REQUEST['password'] == 'pass' ) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        unset( $_COOKIE['retry'];
    } else if ( isset( $_COOKIE['retry'] ) ) {
        setcookie( 'retry', $_COOKIE['retry'] + 1);
    } else {
        setcookie( 'retry', 1 );
    }
}
```

2. Store username, timestamp, login_retry and request ip in a database and use in a similar way.

**EDIT:** After reviewing the comments here, I see sessions are really not a good idea! Cookies would be a better solution! You can also check out [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [redis](http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-redis-in-php-using-predis/). I have not tried them!

Comment: 3. Store it in memcached/redis

Comment: @Robert you are correct...

Comment: Also session is not good idea because after you close browser it's destroyed. The best solution is to use either redis/memcached or DB and store ip too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say save a cookie and update the value each time the user enters the wrong password, start with 1, update to 2 etc, and if the count has reached 5 display a message on the screen informing the user that they have exceeded the number of wrong login attempts.

You can then either set the cookie to expire in an hour or save the time in the cookie and use it to check if an hour has passed

Comment: trouble with that solution is, a hacker would easily bypass the cookie and thus get an infinite number of attempts. The safe solution is to handle users at the server end.

Comment: and I'd say I write bot that ignores cookies and does brute force or dictionary attack on your website.

Comment: I stand corrected, server side it is :)